# Casting from uint16_t to int32_t needs an intermediate cast to int16_t

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, unsigned, signed

See my below code. I'm confused as to why I need to cast the variable `var_u16` to an *int16_t* first before casting to the *int32_t* to be interpreted correctly as a signed int in MyFunc().

I would have thought that as `var_u16` has the most significant bit as one, when simply casting to an *int32_t*, the compiler would understand that this is a negative value.

Instead, it is interpreted as an unsigned value still. Why the need for the intermediate casting to *int16_t* first?

I am using gcc 8.3.0

```
#include <stdio.h>

void MyFunc(int32_t s32Var)
{
    printf("%d\n", s32Var);
}

int main()
{
    uint16_t var_u16 = 0x8000;
    MyFunc((int32_t)var_u16);          // prints 32768  
    MyFunc((int32_t)(int16_t)var_u16); // prints -32768 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What's happening here is that the *value* is getting converted from an unsigned 16 bit number to a signed 32 bit number.  The underlying *representation* isn't relevant.

Since any value that can be stored in an `uint16_t` can also be stored in an `int32_t`, the value is unchanged when converted to the new type.  So an `uint16_t` with the value 32768 becomes a `int32_t` with the value 32768.

Things change with the intermediate cast to `int16_t` because the value 32768 cannot be stored in that type, so the value undergoes an implementation-defined conversion, resulting in the expression with type `int16_t` having the value -32768.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the value is unchanged. This happens because `int32_t` can represent all values of `uint16_t`. When you cast it, you keep the value `0x8000`, it's simply padded with zeros.

> the compiler would understand that this is a negative value

This is incorrect. `0x8000` is a perfectly valid positive number if both representations.

`int16_t` can't hold all values of `uint16_t`, and `0x8000` is one of those values. Instead, `32768` becomes `-32768` in this case. When you cast to `int32_t`, you sign-extend the `int16_t`, keeping the `-32768`.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Thanks

Comment: Your statement "Instead, 32768 becomes -32768". This I don't understand perfectly. Won't the bit representation be still exactly the same tho? I guess i'm trying to understand what is happening under the hood exactly. Will there be some flag then to say that this value should now be treated as signed?

Comment: In two's complement representation of 16 bits, the bit pattern `0x8000` is equivalent to the number -32768. In an unsigned representation, the bit pattern `0x8000` is equivalent to 32768. You're asking `int16_t` to hold the number 32768, which is something that it's completely incapable to doing.

Comment: I know, but in terms of what is happening underneath with the compiler with this. How does it know that when we cast to int16_t , that it should now treat this value as a signed value, even tho the bit patterns are still the same?

Comment: The compiler generates code that treats in a specific way. Nothing tags any variable as a specific type. Based on the code you give it, the compiler knows exactly what type everything is. If it knows it's signed, then it generates instructions that uses it as signed. If it knows it's 16-bit, it generates instructions that use it as 16-bit.

Comment: That's it. Thanks for your replies. I guess I should learn more about the assembly code generated in this case to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

An object of the type `int32_t` can store a value of the type `uint16_t`.

From the C Standard (6.2.6.2 Integer types)

> 5 The values of any padding bits are unspecified.54) **A valid
>   (non-trap) object representation of a signed integer type where the
>   sign bit is zero is a valid object representation of the corresponding
>   unsigned type, and shall represent the same value**.

When an object of a signed integer type as for example `int16_t` is converted to a larger integer type as for example `int32_t` when if this object has a negative value then its sign bit is propagated up to the size of the larger integer type.

So for example if you have the following declaration

```
signed char c = -1;
```

then it has the internal representation in two's compliment system like

```
11111111
```

If yo convert it int16_t or uint16_t then like

```
int16_t i = c;
uint17_t ui = c;
```

then in the both cases the internal representations will look mlike

```
11111111 11111111
```

However if you have an object of the unsigned character type like

```
unsigned char c = 255;
```

that has the internal representation like

```
11111111
```

then in this case the variables i and ui declared like

```
int16_t i = c;
uint17_t ui = c;
```

will have the following internal representation

```
00000000 11111111
```

because the value `255` is a valid value for objects of these types.